# Angular reactive form submit by button click

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I need to submit the Angular reactive form using the other button clicked rather than the submit button.

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm" (submit)="updateProduct($event)" novalidate>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <mat-label>Product Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Product Name" aria-label="Product Name" formControlName="Name" maxlength="70" required>
     </mat-form-field>
</form>

<button class="btn btn-md btn-primary text-upper" type="button">Save</button>
```

I don't have the submit button and I need when the save button will be clicked then the form will be submit and `productForm.value` will be also fetched.

Comment: Change `type="button"` to `type="submit"` of your save button.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
template.html

```
<button class="btn btn-md btn-primary text-upper" type="button" (click)="updateProduct()">Save</button>
```

component.ts

```
updateProduct() {
 console.log(this.productForm.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form [formGroup]="productForm" novalidate>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
    <mat-label>Product Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Product Name" aria-label="Product Name" formControlName="Name" maxlength="70" required>
     </mat-form-field>
</form>
    <button (click)="updateProduct($event)" class="btn btn-md btn-primary text-upper" type="submit">Save</button>
```

Edited. Use click event with your method on button.

Comment: I know its possible in button type=submit but I was asking about type=button.

Comment: Sorry my bad. Then you should use your method with button (click)="".

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare local variable.
2. assign default values to form controls
3. Update component HTML

**app.component.ts**

```
productForm: FormGroup
this.productForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  Name : [""]
})
private Save()
{
   console.log(this.productForm.value)
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button class="btn btn-md btn-primary text-upper" type="button" (click)="Save()">Save</button>
```

also add [formGroup] = "productForm" in input button